# ASP.Net Bundle CSS style

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bundle, web-optimization

I'm trying to make the bundle for all my stylesheets in a WebForm website.
I've succesfully bundled all the scripts but CSS is giving me problem.

this is the bundle.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/_css/BaseSite">
    <include path="~/_css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <include path="~/_css/AdminLTE.css" />
    <include path="~/_css/Admin_all-skins.css" />
    <include path="~/_css/Site_Custom.css" />
    <include path="~/_css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

and I call the bundle in the head of the .aspx page this way:

```
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/_css/BaseSite" />
```

it renders in:

```
    <link href="/_css/BaseSite" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

but no style is loaded. If I click on /_css/BaseSite I get a 404
compilation debug is set to false.

where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding

```
<add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
```

in the web.config to modules in system.webServer